# Perl: Matching 3 pairs of numbers from 4 consecutive numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing some code and I need to do the following:

Given a 4 digit number like "1234" I need to get 3 pairs of numbers (the first 2, the 2 in the middle, and the last 2), in this example I need to get "12" "23" and "34".

I am new to perl and don't know anything about regex. In fact, I am writing a script for personal use and I've started reading about Perl some days ago because I figured it was going to be a better language for the task at hand (need to do some statistics with the numbers and find patterns)

I have the following code but when testing I processed 6 digit numbers, because I "forgot" that the numbers I would be processing are 4 digits, so it failed with the real data, of course

```
foreach $item (@totaldata)
{
    my $match;

    $match = ($item =~ m/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/);

    if ($match) 
    { 
    ($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i], $arr3[$i]) = ($item =~ m/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/);
    $processednums++; 
    $i++;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: $match = ($item =~ m/(\d\d)(\d\d)/); actually is $match = ($item =~ m/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/);  I mistyped

Comment: what do you want?do you want to restrict your input to 4 digits?

Comment: @rock321987 no, the input will be 4 digit numbers, a list of 4 digit numbers that I save by hand into a text file. In another part of the code I've already chomped the file and saved into an array. I just want to match 3 pairs of numbers from a 4 digit number. If the number is 6572 I want to match 65, 57 and 72.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty loud example demonstrating how you can use `substr()` to fetch out the portions of the number, while ensuring that what you're dealing with is in fact exactly a four-digit number.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($one, $two, $three);

while (my $item = <DATA>){
    if ($item =~ /^\d{4}$/){
        $one   = substr $item, 0, 2;
        $two   = substr $item, 1, 2;
        $three = substr $item, 2, 2;
        print "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
1234
abcd
a1b2c3
4567
891011
```

Output:

```
one: 12, two: 23, three: 34
one: 45, two: 56, three: 67
```

Comment: Thank you. Using this I could figure out how to apply it to my code and it seems it worked (at least run processing what it seems to be all the numbers, they are 60*3 so I will check carefully later). I am going to select your answer sincei it made the code run, although the other users helped me a lot too, and since I am new to perl I will try to figure why their approaches did not work (probably my fault) to learn some other ways.

Answer (score 4):

You can move last matching position with [`pos()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

> pos directly accesses the location used by the regexp engine to store the offset, so assigning to pos will change that offset..

```
my $item = 1234;

my @arr;
while ($item =~ /(\d\d)/g) {
  push @arr, $1;
  pos($item)--;
}
print "@arr\n"; # 12 23 34
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you use it in the context of my code ? I see you are using an array but in the code I am assigning them direcrly into 3 different arrays (that I need to use later, thats why). And right now I cant figure out a way without making a tremendous mess.

Comment: You can assign variables after the while loop, `($heads[$i], $middles[$i], $tails[$i]) = @arr;`

Comment: I am trying it but still it does not work for me. I changed something in your code and I am not sure if it has the same meaning "/g" for "\G" . If I leave the former I get syntax error, but with the later it runs but says "No data for processing found" Which is an message that prints if $processednums = 0

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use a global regex pattern search

It is nearly always best to separate *verificaton* of the input data from *processing*, so the program below first rejects any values that are not four characters long or that contain a non-digit character

Then the regex pattern finds all points in the string that are followed by two digits, and captures them

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for my $val ( qw/ 1234 6572 / ) {

    next if length($val) != 4 or $val =~ /\D/;

    my @pairs = $val =~ /(?=(\d\d))/g;
    print "@pairs\n";
}
```

#### output

```
12 23 34
65 57 72
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach $item (@totaldata) {
    if ( my @match = $item =~ m/(?=(\d\d))/ ) {
        ($heads[$i], $middles[$i], $tails[$i]) = @match;
        $processednums++; 
        $i++;
    }
}
```